# How to Extract current date, parse it and add 7 days

Tags: c#, datetime

I'd like to do this :

1. Extract the current date;
2. Parse it as DD/MM/YYYY;
3. Add to it 7 days;

How can I do it on C#?

I hope there are specific methods for do it (without extraxt, split, arrange arrays, join, ecc...).

#### SOLUTION TAKEN

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
txtArrivo.Text = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
txtPartenza.Text = dt.AddDays(7).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: We won't be able to help with step 1 until we know what your data look like.

Comment: I mean actual date! (the date of today... :))

Comment: The solution you took is **absolute nonsense**. `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());` --> Just use `DateTime.Today`!

Comment: You are using the current time, converting it to a string and parsing that string back into a DateTime. WHY? If you want to have todays date, just use `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as that:

```
DateTime inSevenDays = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7);
```

No need to parse anything.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Extract the actual data".  But I'm assuming your getting the value back in a string form.  If so then you can do the following

```
string data = ...;
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(data).AddDays(7);
```

Or to be more precise you can do the following

```
string data = ...;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
  data,
  "dd/MM/yyyy",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(7);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime to parse it and then use AddDays(7) to add 7 days to the DateTime object

Answer (score 1):

Here you go for Ex st is the string where you have the date:

```
        string st = "12/01/2011";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(st).AddDays(7);
        Console.Write(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateString = "05/01/2009";
try {
   dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
   dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(7);
}
catch {
 // something wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the dates are always in DD/MM/YYYY format, then use:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).AddDays(7);
```